# How to store key value pairs

Tags: python, keyvaluepair

I want to store key-value pairs, but I don't know how to do it.

What I want to achieve is a variable that would store the different value pairs.

What I would want is something like this:

```py
dic = {}
valuepair = (2,3), "cell1"
```

Each value pair is unique and I would want to be able to do something like this:

```py
dic[(2,3)] = "cell1"
dic["cell1"] = (2,3)
```

Is there a way to achieve something like that for many different unique value pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask if you can use a tuple as a key - yes, for example:

```
dic[(2,3)] = "cell1"

print(dic[(2,3)])
```

would show cell1

or create an inverse dict like this:

```
inverse_d = {v:k for key, value in d}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key-Value pair means a key mapped to a value. And what you are doing is right, but if you got the key, you can get value from it. So you need not store value ("cell1"), again as a key, when it is already a value. Sorry, if I don't get your question. Or you can do this too:

```
x = [("k1","v1"),("k2,"v2")]
d = dict(x)
print(d)
```

OUTPUT : {"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}

Comment: Yeah I said it wrong, what I would want is to store key-key pairs. So depending on which key you use to call the dic it would return the other key as if it where the value.

Comment: So you want to map two keys in a dictionary and also store values for the same keys in the same dictionary?? Why so, I mean why would you need to do that (as asked by @Austin) ?? In that case, I recommend you to follow the same method and replace "v1", "v2", with "k2", "k1". But use a separate dictionary for that, it will help in avoiding confusion. All the best :)

Comment: Yeah, I will make an inverse of the original dic, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can always do that, but why would you need that is still a question.

```
valuepairs = [[(2,3), "cell1"], [(4,5), "cell2"]]

dic = {}
for x, y in valuepairs:
    dic[x] = y
    dic[y] = x

print(dic)
# {(2, 3): 'cell1', 'cell1': (2, 3), (4, 5): 'cell2', 'cell2': (4, 5)}
```

Comment: I would like to know if theres a method like that but without having to double the size of the dict, but this is what I want. I want something like that because at the beginning I calculate the position for each cell with a funciton, and later I need to know the cell associated with a particular space.

Comment: @DanielCasasampera, so probably you might need to inverse the dictionary that you already have.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it, Thanks alot!